# WP-CLI export returns a bunch of authors not needed for the exported items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-cli

When using this command in WP-CLI I get both the five wanted order items as well as some 100+ unwanted authors:

`wp export --dir=exports/ --start_date=2021-09-06 --post_type=shop_order --author=1 --skip_comments`

Why are these authors added to begin with, they have nothing with the query to do, and is there a way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Try `--post_author=1` or `--user=johndoe` instead. See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/export/.

```
# Export posts published by the user between given start and end date
$ wp export --dir=/tmp/ --user=admin --post_type=post --start_date=2011-01-01 --end_date=2011-12-31
Starting export process...
Writing to file /tmp/staging.wordpress.2016-05-24.000.xml
Success: All done with export.
```

Comment: `--post_author=1` throws and unknown parameter error. The problem is not that the filter doesn't work, it does, I get exactly the items I expect to receive. 

The problem lies in the return of hundreds of author objects that have no connection to the export at all. I would understand if these were customer objects that are connected to the five order posts I receive, but in that case they should be max five.

Comment: Did you also try `--user`?